# How can I fire many HTTP requests using a single TCP connection?

Tags: http, tcp, keepalive

I would like to know if there is a way to open a single TCP connection to a server and request several pages over HTTP on that connection.

Is there a way to do this using common Linux client tools?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5845/are-tool-requests-on-topic

Comment: @techie007 I think this question is fine - he's just asking "how do I do _x_", really.

Comment: @nhinkle Then perhaps it should be edited and reworded to avoid being closed as a Tool Request?

Comment: @nhinkle & techie007 .. y don't u guys show me so i can learn ??

Comment: @Arun good point. Done! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of the pages you want in a file and then use *wget* to download them.

```
wget -i url_list.txt
```